# Create XML in stored procedure in db2

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, triggers, db2, db2-400

I have the following scenario in Iseries:

table(relational data) -> before insert trigger -> calls stored procedure -> saves XML to (XML table) -> after insert trigger(XML table) -> send to MQ.

The trigger uses some data from the NEW row to call the
store procedure, I use the input paramameters for XML data and to query other tables so as to build XML. The table where I save the XML that I built contains the following columns company_id(char), sending_date(date-time), id(integer) and data(XML).  The input parameter company_id in the stored procedure is saved also in the XML. An example for company_id is 1MAE00, that is stored correctly in relational column company_id, but in the XML I see it as 8fH58vDxQA== . It seems that it is a base64 but I'm not 100% sure that it is.  This conversion occurs for alphanumeric data not for numeric data that appears correctly in XML.
I need help to solving this issues as to why the IN parameters in procedure I can save perfectly in relational column but it doesn't work out in XML column

Example store procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIX.ADD_REPORT_FROM_AOF04_PROCEDURE (
        IN FECHA NUMERIC(6,0),
        IN HORA CHAR(6),
        IN AGENTE NUMERIC(5,0),
        IN OPERADOR CHAR(2),
        IN NROORDEN CHAR(13),
        IN ORDER_STATUS CHAR(1))
    LANGUAGE SQL

P1: BEGIN

    DECLARE EXEC_ID INTEGER;
    DECLARE FROM_COMP_ID CHAR(7);
    
    SET EXEC_ID = NEXT VALUE FOR DBDEV.REPORT_SEQ;
    SET SEND_COMP_ID = CONCAT(AGENTE, OPERADOR);
    
    INSERT INTO FIX.EXECUTION_REPORT (COMPANY_ID, SEND_DATE, EXEC_ID, DATA)
        VALUES(
        TARGET_COMP_ID,
        CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('20',SUBSTR(FECHA, 1, 2)), '-'),SUBSTR(FECHA, 3, 2)),'-'),SUBSTR(FECHA, 5, 2)),
        EXEC_ID,
     XMLDOCUMENT(
      XMLELEMENT (NAME "Report",
           XMLELEMENT (NAME "Header",
           XMLELEMENT (NAME "SendFromCompID",
             CONCAT(
              SUBSTR(AGENTE, 1, 1), 'MAE00')),
          XMLELEMENT (NAME "SendToCompID",
             SEND_COMP_ID),
           XMLELEMENT (NAME "SendingTime",
             TO_CHAR(
              TIMESTAMP(
                CONCAT(
                  CONCAT(
                    CONCAT(
                      CONCAT(
                        CONCAT('20',
                           SUBSTR(FECHA, 1, 2)), '-'),
                       SUBSTR(FECHA, 3, 2)),
                    '-'),
                   SUBSTR(FECHA, 5, 2)),
                 CONCAT(
                  CONCAT(
                    CONCAT(
                      CONCAT(SUBSTR(HORA, 1, 2), '.'),
                       SUBSTR(HORA, 3, 2)),
                    '.'),
                   SUBSTR(HORA, 5, 2))) - CURRENT TIMEZONE, 'yyyymmdd-hh24:mm:ss'))),
        XMLELEMENT (NAME "OrderID", NEXT VALUE FOR DBDEV.REPORT_ORD_ID_SEQ),
         XMLELEMENT (NAME "ClOrdID", TRIM(NROORDEN)),
         XMLELEMENT (NAME "ExecID", EXEC_ID),
         XMLELEMENT (NAME "StandardTrailer",
         XMLELEMENT (NAME "CheckSumData", 0)))));
END P1
```

Comment: please edit your question to show your code for the insert into the table with the XML colum, showing the data-types and sample data in the host-variables/literals.

Comment: Added example store procedure

Comment: What is the definition for `send_comp_id` and `target_comp_id` and where do they get set in the procedure ? Have you checked their runtime values?   Are you sure the datatypes of parameters match the arguments supplied by the trigger?